# How do I prove that the boundary of a set has the property that an open ball around it will have at least one interior and one exterior point?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Boundary point of a set S, as per definition, is a point which is neither exterior nor interior to S.
Interior point of a set S, as per definition, is a point for which there exists an open ball of some radius $r>0$ around it such that every point within that open ball belongs to the set S.
Exterior point of a set S, as per definition, is a point for which there exists an open ball of some radius $r>0$ around it such that none of the points within that open ball belong to the set S.

P.S.: The metric space being considered is $R^n$

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to ask that if $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $x \in \operatorname{Bd}(S)$, then every ball around $x$ contains an interior point of $S$ and an exterior point of $S$, then this is false. Just take $n=1$ and $S = \mathbb{Q}$, which has no interior or exterior points.

What *is* true, almost by definition, is that every ball around $x$ contains points not in $S$ (or else $x$ would be interior to $S$!) and points in $S$ (or else $x$ would be exterior to $S$). This basically holds due to the the facts the boundary is *defined* as those points that are neither interior nor exterior to $S$, plus what these negations mean in terms of open balls.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.. Just a follow-up question, when can my hypothesis be true, i.e. under what conditions on S, will the boundary of the set have the above mentioned property?

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample: $S = \{P\}$ where $P$ is a single point of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I guess he means that the interior of $S$ is not empty.

Comment: @ChrisKerridge: It is easy enough to provide counterexamples in that situation too.

Comment: I can see that the "dual" of your example fits this $S = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \left\{p\right\}$ but then $S$ has no exterior points. What about beyond these degenerate cases?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hint]

**hint**: Hope this helps you, just play with the metric, BUT you are missing some hypothesis.